# preventing any backtracking in regex past a specific pattern

Tags: regex

Is it possible with regex (in any advanced implementation, ie: PERL, Ruby, python regex module) to disallow ANY backtracking past a specific matching pattern ?

Here's a simple case: Say I want to make a regex that has to validate a simple language. This language is composed of:

- only digits (`0` to `9`)
- `@` followed by `a` or `b`.

Please note that empty string is valid.

So these are valid: `""`, `"123"`, `"@a"`, `"1@b"`, `"@a123"`, and these are invalid: `"X"`, `"@"`, `"@@"`, `"@1"`, `"a"`, `"@aa"`.

I want to build a regex that match valid case and do not match invalid cases (fails).
With the catch that:

- I'm using matching function that search from the beginning of the string, but do not force for full matchs... I'd like a solution that avoids these and **so please don't use `$` to match the end of the string.** This is at best a workaround, we **know** that the string won't match without having to check the end of the string. I must add that I can't use this because my toy language could be used in wider language, and the given string wouldn't end there... this wouldn't break the fact that we **know** that the string won't match our syntax before checking at the position of the end of the string or the content of the remaining string.
- Note that there is no need to do any backtracking if we match `@` and it fails matching `a` or `b` after it because the whole string will fail matching the given syntax.
- I need the regex to FAIL not match part of the string.

The regex I would like to write is something like:

```
 (@![ab]|[0-9]|!(?!))*
```

With a twist: the `!` characters is from my imagination and would disallow backtracking if encountered, if the remaining string doesn't match the remaining pattern, then the whole pattern will fail matching the whole string. Notice then that `!(?!)` as the last alternative will make the whole pattern fail if encountered.

I've looked into **atomic grouping**, and **possessive quantifiers**, but I can't see how to emulate the wanted result with them.

Here's a simple way to setup a test environment:

```
pip install regex &&
cat <<EOF > ./test_regex.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, regex

def check_regex(rx, *strings):
    for string in strings:
        m = regex.match(rx, string)
        print("match %-4s for %r" %
              ("Fail" if m is None else m.end(), string))

check_regex(*sys.argv[1:])
EOF
chmod +x test_regex.py
```

And then, here's the test command, and followed by it's awaited output: can you fill in MYSTERY_REGEX ?

```
./test_regex.py MYSTERY_REGEX "" "123" "@a" "1@b" "@a123" "X" "@" "@@" "@1" "a" "@aa"
match 0    for ''
match 3    for '123'
match 2    for '@a'
match 3    for '1@b'
match 5    for '@a123'
match Fail for 'X'
match Fail for '@'
match Fail for '@@'
match Fail for '@1'
match Fail for 'a'
match Fail for '@aa'
```

Please note that `(@[ab]|[0-9])*$` is a simple answer that will produce the correct output, BUT it's using a final `$` which is explicitely forbidden here.

**So can you remove the need of checking full matches ?** If you can't, can you elaborate on why do you think it's not possible ?

Comment: Please note that what I'd like is very similar to PROLOG's ``!`` (more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29)

Comment: I know, this question is very old, but the answer I think is negative lookahead. Btw, the `!(?!)` part doesn't make sense if this should be matched in a larger language. I remove it:
`(@[ab]|[0-9])*+(?![@0-9])`
If you want to match end of the string, you can add it again: `(@[ab]|[0-9])*+(?!.)`

Answer (score 2):

To limit the backtracking with the regex module:

```
^[0-9]*+(?>@[ab])?[0-9]*+$
```

Note that you **need** to use anchors.

if several parts with @ are allowed:

```
^[0-9]*+(?>@[ab][0-9]++)*(?>@[ab])?[0-9]*+$
```

Comment: Well, if you use the anchor ``(@[ab]|[0-9])*$`` will suffice... and this means we don't force a failure. I want to avoid '$' because my little toy language could be included in a greater language, and thus the string might not end there, but nevertheless, the regex matching should fail and it's not the fact that we reached the end of the string that makes the string unmatched. But thanks for your efforts ;)

Comment: @vaab: In this case, using atomic groups and possessive quantifiers should not suffice, you must replace the two anchors with lookarounds with allowed characters before and after the match. Example: after `@a`, `[ab]` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It's [possible using the `:` modifier in Perl 6](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes.html#Preventing_backtracking%3A_%3A) but in this case, it would probably be better to use [grammars](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial)

Comment: For whatever reason Perl 6 had to depart so much from regex conventions, it took me a while to understand, this answer is not related to the question but actually Perl 6's weird replacement notation for possessive quantifiers. Perl 6 turns `?+`, `*+` and `++` into `?:` , `*:` and `+:`. Possessive quantifiers don't throw every existing backtracking point but only those created by a specific quantifier. The use case being advertised in the docs is also kind of odd, parsing tokens without explicit token separation. I thought, only my mind came up with whacky stuff like that.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph the original question is simply tagged `regex`: choose whatever regex engine you prefer! The OP specifically asks about Perl,  Ruby, and Python, so I'm guessing Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) is fair game. Cheers.

Comment: I am sorry. My comment might've been too indirect. I was not critizing the usage of Riku's syntax in this answer (it is horribly unintuitive though, yes). I wanted to indicate the problems of this answer. First, the lack of an appropriate explanation (the referent documentation is as unclear as Riku's Regex syntax itself). Second, thinking of the *mere* syntactical change of Riku's identical concepts as the solution of the problem. It looked as if the author misunderstood the syntactical change as a semantical change. And grammars certainly deviate from the question, therefore no good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found the answer browsing the PCRE2 docs in the section about "backtracking verbs".

There is a backtracking verb `(*COMMIT)` which means as much as "force the subsequent RegExp part to match or fail to match any further thing". With "subsequent RegExp part" I mean the part right after `(*COMMIT)`. The subsequent RegExp part may be delimited by the closing parenthesis `)` inside an atomic group or assertion (like lookahead or lookbehind).

Let's apply it to your idea:

```
(@(*COMMIT)[ab]|[0-9])+
```

It will not find empty matches. As the OP requests, it doesn't have to match until the end of subject string.

Whenever it reads `@` it progresses to the immediate left side of `(*COMMIT)` backtracking verb. It then passes through it to the right. Then, if no `[ab]` is matched, it tries to backtrack but when backtracking flow reaches the right side of `(*COMMIT)`, trying to go to the left side of it, the whole match attempt will fail. **When it fails with `(*COMMIT)`, it will not even try new match attempts** according to the documentation [here](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC29), cf. section "Verbs that act after backtracking"

> Even if the pattern is unanchored, no further attempts to find a match
> by advancing the starting point take place. If (*COMMIT) is the only
> backtracking verb that is encountered, once it has been passed
> pcre2_match() is committed to finding a match at the current starting
> point, or not at all.

This does not mean, it cannot find multiple occurences but it will stop searching for new matches when a `(*COMMIT)` fails the first time. That means, it will not throw away already found matches from earlier successful attempts.

There is another backtracking verb `(*PRUNE)` which also fails an entire match attempt when backtracking control flow would pass through it from right to left. But unlike `(*COMMIT)` it allows for further match attempts. I don't understand the comparison with `(*COMMIT)` that is made in the documentation but I tested `(*PRUNE)` with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) which also gives nice explanations.

And if you need more control regarding at which subject characters the new match attempt **may not** be started, you can use `(*SKIP)` or `(*SKIP:`<name>`)`. `(*SKIP)` is like `(*PRUNE)` but additionally requires every new match attempt to start at the right of it, i.e. after the character which was last matched before the `(*SKIP)` was reached. The optional name can refer to another place – annotated by `(*MARK:`<name>`)` – used for skipping new match attempts. It will search for the MARK by retreating backwards through the string (not entering assertions or atomic groups again) and when the appropriate mark was not found, `(*SKIP)` will be ignored according to documentation.

`(*SKIP)` is like modifying the latest backtracking point so that it points to a new location. In many situations however, this not a functional addition and merely serves optimization which makes it questionable in regards to readability. I would like an intelligent engine to infer such "skips" automatically for performance optimization.

##### Useful example for `(*SKIP)`:

- language of subject string: (abab|abac)*
- desired match inside subject string: `abab` (but no overlapping with `abac`)
- PCRE2 solution: `aba(*SKIP)b`

Comment: Afaik features like commit and prune were introduced into PCRE after they were "stolen" from Perl's regexes, which in turn stole from Raku, which in turn stole from Prolog. (The earliest original source I've found for now for Raku is [a doc with edit dates 2002 thru 2006](https://github.com/Raku/raku.org/blob/22f4017c98514f5ff462a95e0b57ff626f80180b/source/archive/doc/design/apo/A05.pod). I'm currently unable to access archive.org for other sources, but believe the evolution was roughly Raku -> Perl -> PCRE over a decade or so.)

Comment: Makes sense I think. Such a type of feature would fit to Prolog. Raku had been called "Perl 6" some time ago, so the Perl maintainers likely have a closer look at what Raku is doing.